# CucumberOptions doesn't run features

Tags: java, selenium, junit, cucumber

After a few years of coding in Cucumber I got strange error when trying to execute the tests:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.runner.Description.createSuiteDescription(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/io/Serializable;[Ljava/lang/annotation/Annotation;)Lorg/junit/runner/Description;
    at io.cucumber.junit.FeatureRunner.getDescription(FeatureRunner.java:118)
    at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber.describeChild(Cucumber.java:191)
    at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber.describeChild(Cucumber.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.getDescription(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.getDescription(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:79)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

TestRunner class:

```
package codelab.runners;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        glue = {"codelab.step", "codelab.page", "codelab.hooks", "codelab.helpers", "codelab.api"},
        features = "src/test/resources/features/",
        plugin = {"json:target/cucumber.json", "pretty"})
public class TestRunner {
}
```

The error is strictly related to feature path provided in @CucumberOptions annotation. The path is correct and I have no idea why it suddenly stopped working...

POM.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>codelab</groupId>
    <artifactId>babel_guru_selenium</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <properties>
        <projectName>BabelGuru</projectName>
        <reportInputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</reportInputDirectory>
        <reportOutputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-report-html</reportOutputDirectory>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>

                    <execution>
                        <id>selenium</id>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <file>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/lib/JARs/SeleniumHelper.jar</file>
                            <groupId>codelab</groupId>
                            <artifactId>SeleniumHelper</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0</version>
                            <packaging>jar</packaging>
                            <pomFile>D:/projects/quality_assurance/Engines/SeleniumHelper/pom.xml</pomFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>webdriver</id>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <file>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/lib/JARs/WebDriverFactory.jar</file>
                            <groupId>codelab</groupId>
                            <artifactId>WebDriverFactory</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0</version>
                            <packaging>jar</packaging>
                            <pomFile>D:/projects/quality_assurance/Engines/WebDriverFactory/pom.xml</pomFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>restAssured</id>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <file>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/lib/JARs/RestAssuredEngine.jar</file>
                            <groupId>codelab</groupId>
                            <artifactId>RestAssuredHelper</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0</version>
                            <packaging>jar</packaging>
                            <pomFile>D:/projects/quality_assurance/Engines/RestAssuredHelper/pom.xml</pomFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>./src/main/resources/profiles/${build.profile.id}</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>

    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.8</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>codelab</groupId>
            <artifactId>RestAssuredHelper</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>codelab</groupId>
            <artifactId>SeleniumHelper</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>codelab</groupId>
            <artifactId>WebDriverFactory</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>[4.10]</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <profiles>

        <profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <properties>
                <build.profile.id>local</build.profile.id>
            </properties>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <build.profile.id>dev</build.profile.id>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>test</id>
            <properties>
                <build.profile.id>test</build.profile.id>
            </properties>
        </profile>

    </profiles>

</project>
```

Any help would be really appriciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Sup with that Junit version?

Comment: It's a strict usage of 4.10 version, not any newer.

Comment: And exactly which method couldn't be found by  cucumber?

Comment: The one, you can see in a stacktrace. Right now I noticed, that if I have an empty Feature file, for example with commented out scenarios, TestRunner can access it. Of course it doesn't run anything but doesn'r throw an exception either. With a scenario an exception is thrown again...

Comment: So you've told your build system to use a very specific version of JUnit. And you've got Cucumber complaining that it can't find a JUnit method. You may want to connect the dots.

Comment: It's not that. Before it ran with 4.13.2 - the newest one and it suddenly stopped working :/ That whyh I tied many different versions of jUnit but none of it helps.

Comment: You should not put any junit version to your pom. `cucmber-junit` already have a dependency it stably works with. If you set it in your pom you override that dependency.

Comment: Your issue is definitely related to junit version. I've just tested that cucumber 7.0.0 throws the exception like you show if you use JUnit 4.10, but everything works fine with 4.13.2 that is a dependency of cucumber 7.0.0. If you're saying that it is reproducible even with 4.13.2 I would recommend to fix your pom (remove explicit junit dependency), then `mvn clean test` and update your question with relevant error message.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm this is a tough one. I am not really sure why are you specifying the glue path to classes like "step", "hooks", "helpers" etc.
The glue path defines the package in which stepDefinitions are found.
This is an example from one of my projects:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)

@CucumberOptions(  monochrome = true,
        tags = "@tags",
        features = "src/test/resources/",
        format = { "pretty","html: cucumber-html-reports",
                "json: cucumber-html-reports/cucumber.json" },
        dryRun = false,
        glue = "stepMethods" )
```

stepMethods being the package where my step definitions are.
Maybe just try and go with this (in your scenario):

```
glue = "codelab"
```

Good luck :)